# Factory reset a woo tablet

Tags: factory-reset

I tried to reset a woo tablet 7" without success:

1. When pressing [Power button] + [Volume Up] I can see the android icon with the warning icon but nothing happens!
2. pressing [Power button] + [Volume Down] opens a weird menu in a korean-like language.

How I can perform a factory reset on a woo 7" tablet?

### Update

I can't access to the tablet, it's locked with gesture pattern.

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Power Button</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>
2. <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, select recovery mode
3. Open with <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>
4. <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> or <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> to select wipe, then <kbd>Power Button</kbd> to execute

Answer (score 0):

In your settings you should see the category "back up and reset". And there you should see factory data reset. First try this. 
The strange korean menu is the recovery menu. There you have the reset to factory option too. 
But there are differences between the OS Version and the brand. So you should try to find a guide on google. 
Edit:
I read that the reset option might be in the "privacy options".